# Presenting one ViewController over another partially

Tags: ios, swift, view, uikit, subview

I have a `MapViewController` that is basically a `MKMapView` and presents a map with custom annotations.

Right now I am trying to present another ViewController from the bottom containing additional filters that the user will be able to use on his journey.

However I ran into a problem, when I am presenting the new `FilterMenuViewController` as a child of `MapViewController` the `MapViewController` disappears.

This is what it looks like:

[Initial state](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZnIk.png)

[Button to present new controller tapped](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYCwd.png)

[New controller presented but the MapViewController disappearing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecdPX.png)

The code that takes care of the interaction is as follows:

`MapViewController` variables declaration:

```
var filterMenuVC = FilterMenuViewController()
var isFilterMenuOpened = false
```

`MapViewController viewDidLoad()`:

```
    filterMenuVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FilterMenuViewController") as! FilterMenuViewController
```

`MapViewController showFilterMenu` button action:

```
@IBAction func showFilterMenu(_ sender: UIButton) {
    // Presents the filter menu
    if isFilterMenuOpened == true {
        isFilterMenuOpened = false
        filterMenuVC.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        filterMenuVC.view.removeFromSuperview()
        filterMenuVC.removeFromParentViewController()
    } else if isFilterMenuOpened == false {
        isFilterMenuOpened = true
        self.addChildViewController(filterMenuVC)
        self.view.addSubview(filterMenuVC.view)
        filterMenuVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure the background of the filterMenuVC is clear? What frame/constraints are you applying to filterMenuVC?

Comment: Yes I am 100% sure even with 0 alpha and nothing on the viewController the initial MapViewController gets deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I created a segue "show" from the button to the ViewController which conflicted with adding the controller to the current view, it pushed into it instead and the MapViewController got deallocated.

So I just deleted the segue from sotryboard and added the child programatically, it works like charm now.

Was a stupid mistake, but maybe this will help someone who runs into the same problem :)

Comment: Try the code and imagine this, the black part of the view is because you try to present in all screen, you need to adjust the height, like this:

CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y-308, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 308)

if the start point is the bottom of the screen the CGRect values change:

CGRect.init(x:0,y:self.view.frame.size.height-"yourViewSize",width:self.view.frame.width,height:"yourviewSize")

Comment: Helo I already fixed the problem I just deleted the storyboard segue and added the controller as child programatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the view shows from top and reverse, here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9sa7.jpg

```
if isFilterMenuOpened{
            if let searching = self.childViewControllers.first as? ViewController{
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.7, animations: {
                    searching.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0,
                                                       y: self.view.frame.origin.y-308,
                                                       width: self.view.frame.size.width,
                                                       height: 308)
                }, completion: {(boos) in
                    searching.removeFromParentViewController()
                    searching.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    self.isFilterMenuOpened = false
                })
            }
        }else{
            let search = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "searchView") as! ViewController
            search.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y-308, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 308) //The View controller height same size of your view in storyboard
            search.delegateSearch = self
            self.addChildViewController(search)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
                search.view.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 308)
            })
            self.view.addSubview(search.view)
            self.didMove(toParentViewController: search)
            isFilterMenuOpened = true
        }
```